# Why is CSS transform (via Javascript) not working with more than one function

Tags: javascript, css, styles

Really simple problem, I have a camera which uses transforms to move/zoom/rotate, and I would like it all to be done on the GPU (so, using transform). With one transform (`translate()`), it works fine and has no issues. However, if I add in the other 2, it suddenly becomes an empty string:

```js
namespace `game.modules`(
    class Camera{
        constructor(tag){
            this.tag = tag;
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
            this.rotation = 0;
            this.scaleX = 1;
            this.scaleY = 1;
            this.animations = []
        }

        lookAt(object){
            this.x=object.x;
            this.y=object.y;
        }

        
        onDraw(){
            this.setTagFromData();
        }

        setTagFromData(){
            var x = -(this.x-100);
            var y = -(this.y-60);
            this.tag.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0px)`
            console.log(this.tag.style.transform)
        }
    }
)
```

This outputs the expected string (`translate3d(50px, 50px, 0px)`). However, adding in the other properties like so:

```js
namespace `game.modules`(
    class Camera{
        constructor(tag){
            this.tag = tag;
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
            this.rotation = 0;
            this.scaleX = 1;
            this.scaleY = 1;
            this.animations = []
        }

        lookAt(object){
            this.x=object.x;
            this.y=object.y;
        }

        
        onDraw(){
            this.setTagFromData();
        }

        setTagFromData(){
            var x = -(this.x-100);
            var y = -(this.y-60);
            this.tag.style.transform = `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0px) rotate(${this.ang}deg) scale(${this.scaleX}, ${this.scaleY})`
            console.log(this.tag.style.transform)
        }
    }
)
```

Logs an empty string, not even the `translate3d()`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe because `this.ang` is undefined? CSS ignores invalid values, I wouldn't be surprised if an expression containing `undefined` was discarded altogether

Comment: Yea that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed in the comments :

Since `this.ang` is undefined, the generated string contains the word `undefined` in it, so it is an invalid CSS expression. CSS is known to ignore invalid expression, so the whole string is simply discarded.